# find closest value in prior rows less and greater than current row value in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a table that contains ids and i would like to find the closest value less than and greater than the current row id from all prior row values only. Below is a small sample and output columns i would like to have

```
df<-structure(list(row_id = 1:10, id = c(2, 11, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 10, 
9, 1), min_closest_smaller_prior = c(NA, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 
7, NA), max_close_bigger_prior = c(NA, NA, 11, 11, 5, 11, 11, 
11, 10, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Columns min_closest_smaller_prior  and min_closest_bigger_prior contain the values from the id column looking at prior rows only. For example in the min_closest_bigger_prior column id 11 contains NA because there are no values in the previous rows larger than 11.

Using the answer below i was able to find the closest minimum using the following:

```
 df2 <-
    df %>% mutate(nearest = transform(., close_prev = id[apply(`diag<-`(m <-
                                                                          as.matrix(dist(id)), Inf) / upper.tri(m), 2, which.min)])) %>% as_tibble()
```

Any idea how to find the closest value greater than?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```r
s <- sapply(df$id, `>`, df$id)
smaller <- df$id[apply(s & upper.tri(s), 2, \(x) ifelse(all(!x), NA, max(which(x))))]

b <- sapply(df$id, `<`, df$id)
bigger <- df$id[apply(b & upper.tri(b), 2, \(x) ifelse(all(!x), NA, max(which(x))))]

df$min_closest_smaller_prior <- smaller
df$max_close_bigger_prior <- bigger
df
   row_id id min_closest_smaller_prior max_close_bigger_prior
1       1  2                        NA                     NA
2       2 11                         2                     NA
3       3  3                         2                     11
4       4  5                         3                     11
5       5  4                         3                      5
6       6  6                         4                     11
7       7  7                         6                     11
8       8 10                         7                     11
9       9  9                         7                     10
10     10  1                        NA                      9
```

---

As a function:

```r
closest_prior <- 
  function(x, type){
    if(type == "smaller"){
      vec <- sapply(x, `>`, x)
    }
    else if(type == "bigger"){
      vec <- sapply(x, `<`, x)
    }
    x[apply(vec & upper.tri(vec), 2, \(y) ifelse(all(!y), NA, max(which(y))))]
  }

closest_prior(df$id, type = "smaller")
#[1] NA  2  2  3  3  4  6  7  7 NA

closest_prior(df$id, type = "bigger")
#[1] NA NA 11 11  5 11 11 11 10  9
```

Comment: Thank you! I could not figure this one out. Function is great too!

Comment: one question. Why is id 1 showing 9 in the max_close_bigger_prior column? It should be 2. And Id 6 should be 5 in the min_close_bigger_prior column

Comment: Because 9 is closer to 1 than 2

Comment: i should have stated closest value. Does that make sense. I can refresh my question

Comment: Oh I see. A little modification can be done in the function to make it work

Comment: I'm guessing i need to change this bit of code? max(which(x))

Comment: Yes. It’s not trivial though. I’m on my phone, so I can’t really help you, but you should compute the difference among the bigger/smaller values, and take the one with the smallest differnece

Comment: This has an O(n^2) time complexity and that will be expensive in larger vectors

Comment: I used the following to find the closest value less than but i'm not sure how to change to find the closest value greater than. see below:  df %>% mutate(nearest = transform(., close_prev = id[apply(`diag<-`(m <-
                                                                          as.matrix(dist(id)), Inf) / upper.tri(m), 2, which.min)])) %>% as_tibble()